# Reduce method count of app after integrating Google Play Services Analytics Library

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, android-multidex

I need to integrate the Google Play Services Analytics library, but it contributes 28k methods to my application! I am forced to use multidex, which I would prefer not to in order to keep the size of my app small. Given that Android support libraries contributes 18k, 28k just for Analytics is a bit crazy isn't it? Is there another way shrink this method count bloat?

Here are the dependencies that I am putting in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.+'
compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.1.2'
```

And I am using these tools to calculate method count:
https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/6002797

It is showing me that the com.google package is contributing 28901 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Without using multidex your other option is to strip out parts of libraries you are not using with Proguard.